A single byte that is from 0 to 255 to be rescaled from 0 to 7
A single 1 byte could be from 0 to 255. I intend to rescale it to be from 0 to 7. I have done this:
bit8 := uint8(136)

// To re-scale 1 byte from 0 to 2^3-1 i.e. 0 to 7
bit3 := bit8 / 0xff * 0b0111

The resulting bit3 is 0, but I expect it to be 3 or 4 depending upon rounding down or up. Since the floating point exact value would be 136/255*7 = 3.733333333.
How can I achieve my desired output? Rounding up and down doesn't matter at this point. Whatever is convenient is fine.
Note
I want the operation to be as efficient as possible. Because it's going to be done inside a loop. So, the solutions like below are not optimal:
bit8 := uint8(136)

// To re-scale 1 byte from 0 to 2^3-1 i.e. 0 to 7
bit3 := uint8(float64(bit8) / 255.0 * 7.0)


bit3 := bit8 & 7?

Your first attempt is zero because you're doing integer division and x/255 will always be zero. You can multiply by 7 first but then you'll need a larger int type.

"I expect it to be 3 or 4 depending upon rounding down or up." Integer division doesn't do "rounding" of some intermediate float value like 3.73333.

@matt What's the absolutely fastest way to do so?

Take the top 3 bits of the byte (this rounds down):
bit3 := bit8 >> 5


Just in case, how can I modify it to round up?

@Megidd Rounding integer division (instead of truncating). The method depends on whether you want to round up or to nearest or whatever

Another way to look at this, your scaling 256 to 8, which is x*8/256, that reduces to x/2^5 or x>>5.

@matt That was an amazing explanation. Fabulous.
